# GItHub App access to repositories in organization

Tags: github3.py

I have a Github App created under an organization and is installed to a repository under same organization. I tried reading a file from the same repository after authenticating using github3 login_as_app_installation API. I get below error

```
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github3/repos/repo.py", line 1618, in file_contents
    json = self._json(self._get(url, params={"ref": ref}), 200)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github3/models.py", line 156, in _json
    raise exceptions.error_for(response)
github3.exceptions.ForbiddenError: 403 Resource not accessible by integration
```

But I am able to add issue_comments after authenticating with the same API. Am I missing any permissions or problem is somewhere else?

Comment: What permission does the app have? More importantly, have you given `Contents` to the app?

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne I have added permissions to Contents. I checked again now, there was a request to approve the Read access to code from Github for this app. It started working after explicitly approving it. Thanks, I am closing the issue as fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a request to approve the Read access to code from Github for this app. It started working after explicitly approving it.